# SSD acting weird after taking a hit

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, physical-damage

So, it all began when my PC took a minor hit during transportation. Nothing appears to be damaged visually, and all components are working just fine, except for the SSD (A-DATA Premier Pro SP920). Initially after the incident the OS (Windows 7 x64) crashed while loading with an "Inaccessable boot device" error. My first fixing attemts included:

- Running chkdsk (no effect);
- Replugging all the wiring (no effect);
- Running various disk diagnistics tools (which didn't detect any problems);
- Reinstalling Windows.

The latter one had interesting results. Installation went just fine, OS booted up, but after some time the SSD randomly disconnected from the system. After a hard reset it appears to be working again. That's all I have by now; the post will be updated whenever something else happens.

Motherboard is Gigabyte GA-P55-USB3, AHCI mode is on.

The questions are: how can this behaviour be explained and should I be ordering a new SSD?

UPD1: Some applications installed on the SSD tend to crash with "read permission denied" error.

Comment: It might be worth getting another drive, install OS on it and see how it behaves for a day or two. This would help you identify if its the board or the drive. If the SSD is cosmetically fine, have a crack at claiming on warranty if still within period.

Comment: SSDs have no moving parts.  So you could drop it from a reasonable height all you want, and realistically unless one of the IC chips broke or become delodged, the device would work.  Your problems are unlikely connected to the move

Comment: I know. SSD is supposed to be the toughest part of the system, able to survive stresses like a car crash, if i remember correctly. And that only fuels my curiosity.

Comment: I'd say something may of been knocked loose on the motherboard, or you've managed to bash the cable ports enough that sometimes it's loosing connection. Of course the same could  be happening on the SSD's end too.

Comment: It just doesn't look like losing connection "sometimes". OS booting was crashing at the same point each time. Feels like there's a hole in memory upon which the system stumbles from time to time.